# UEFI dual booting Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, menu

I have raid 0 set up on a system with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04. I can boot to both just fine but I have to do it in the UEFI BIOS.

I would like to have in a boot menu in GRUB. Is that possible? I have tried a few workarounds with no luck.

In GRUB Customizer it does not show the UEFI Windows path at all. I tried some Windows based editors but it just corrupts the boot loader.

After I installed Ubuntu, it would not load I had to run Boot-Repair.

I have added my GRUB config file (`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`). I am not a expert, thanks.

```bash
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/33_linux_proxy ###
menuentry "Ubuntu" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
}
submenu "Advanced options for Ubuntu"{
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-advanced-944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
}
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (recovery mode)" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-recovery-944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/33_linux_proxy ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/34_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/34_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/35_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (14.04) (on /dev/mapper/pdc_ejjdbjffd5)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21
    fi
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (14.04) (on /dev/mapper/pdc_ejjdbjffd5)' $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-advanced-944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu (on /dev/mapper/pdc_ejjdbjffd5)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic.efi.signed--944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (on /dev/mapper/pdc_ejjdbjffd5)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic.efi.signed--944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/mapper/pdc_ejjdbjffd5)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic.efi.signed-root=UUID=944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21 ro recovery nomodeset-944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=944e1cb8-1584-4e54-8a27-455fe241fc21 ro recovery nomodeset
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    }
}

set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/35_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: not sure if this helps at all or not Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
  No volume groups found
Found Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (14.04) on /dev/mapper/pdc_ejjdbjffd5
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done

Comment: When you boot to Linux, is there a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi`?

Comment: im not sure what you mean by when i boot but there is a folder with that path on my system

Answer (score 0):

You're booting Linux in EFI mode, so I don't know why the GRUB configuration scripts aren't picking up the Windows boot loader. The fact that you *can* boot to Windows means that the Windows boot loader *is* present. I have two suggestions.

First, you could edit the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file. Create an entry that resembles the following:

```
menuentry "Windows 8.1" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod chain
    set root='(hd0,gpt1)'
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

You may need to change `(hd0,gpt1)` to `(hd0,gpt2)` or some other value, though, depending on the partition number of your [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition). Once you've created that entry, type `sudo update-grub` to update your main GRUB configuration file. When you reboot and select Linux from the firmware's boot manager, Windows should appear as an option.

Another possibility is to try my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) I recommend doing this by first trying the CD-R or USB flash driver version, available on the program's [downloads page.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) rEFInd should give you options for both Linux and Windows. If both work, then install the Debian package, which should then take over as your primary boot manager.